# canvas has an offset

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am using `<canvas>` to do a checkers board for a class project. For some reason my canvas is starting with an offset and I can't fix it.
[image]

I don't want to post much code because it is an homework assignment, and I don't want people to solve it for me. 
I did try to put `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` , but it is not working.
what I am basically doing is a nested for loop of i and j from 0 to 8.
and I am changing the colors based on even/odd location. After i decided my color, I am doing `ctx.fillRect(i*50 ,j*50,50,50)`

any idea where this offset can come from?
thanks

Comment: Can you tell if this is an offset within the canvas, or whether it is an offset of your canvas in the DOM? I would guess the latter, and that you can fix this with CSS.

Comment: Have you tried resetting CSS? http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: The offset is inside the canvas, if I do ctx.fillRect(i*50 +10 ,j*50,50,50) , the board will move inside this grey area, and the lines will still stay there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the size of your canvas 400 x 400? And is there a container that is holding the canvas with a background with that gray color (#808080)?

If so, this is a CSS problem. Try giving the canvas a style of float:left. Or absolutely positioning the canvas within it's container.

```
<canvas width="400" height="400" style="float:left"></canvas>
```

or

```
<div style="position:relative"><!-- containing element -->
    <canvas width="400" height="400" style="top:0; left:0;position:absolute">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: float:left solved the issue. could you explain what was the source of the CSS problem?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your html/css, but the left offset could have been caused by a white-space character. I'm not sure exactly why the offset appears on the bottom, I just know that oftentimes if you don't float an element inside it's container, a small amount of space can appear between the end of the element and the end of the container.

Comment: my canvas is not inside a div container, it is inside a table
        `<td id="rowId">
        <canvas id="gameboard" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        </td>`. Also I am sorry I cannot share code, I don't think it will be fair if I share it, I feel it will allow people to comment on my code and make it better in a way that will give me unfair advantage when it comes to grading